# How to concat date picker value and time picker value in single element?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am using date picker and time picker separately in my vue.js code. My datepicker and time picker are giving me values as:

```
date = "2018-01-19T00:00:00.000Z"
time = "2018-05-20T00:06:30.000Z
```

Both date and time are of object form, from these I want to create a new object like so:

```
dataTime = "2018-01-19T00:06:30.000Z"
```

How to create this and then convert it to ISO string format?

Comment: 1. Concatonating a string has nothing to do with Vue, it's a function of Javascript. 2. Take time to format your posts if you want people to help you.

Comment: yes @Richard Vanbergen is right you can use moment.js  concatenating  string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use momentjs (http://momentjs.com/):

```
var date = moment(dateObject).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
var time = moment(dateObject).format("HH:mm:ss");
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/) as follows:

```js
import {formatISO} from 'date-fns';

const date = new Date();
const time = new Date();
const newDate = formatISO(date, {representation: 'date'});
const newTime = formatISO(time, {representation: 'time'});
const dateTime = `${newDate}T${newTime}`
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in plain Javascript, no need for a library like moment.js.

Here is a verbose example it can be simplified...

```
getDateTime($d,$t){
   let date = $d; //i.e. "2018-01-19T00:00:00.000Z";
   let time = $t; //i.e. "2018-05-20T00:06:30.000Z";

   date = date.split('T').slice(0,1);
   time = time.split('T').slice(1);

   return date + 'T' + time;
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for reply. i tried your solution but facing one problem
date and time are objects in my case so + 'T' is not working for me..
can you suggest me some way?

Comment: In your question you are asking how to concate strings. I don't see the objects in your post.   You need to pass the strings into the function, not objects.  If the pickers are giving you an object then you need to use something like `object.timestamp`  to access the string.  If you need more help than that you need to show us what the object actually looks like.

Comment: @user6376936 you can format your time object to get that string

Answer (score 0):

Most answers here do not take **daylight savings** into account. Concatenating date and time with `T` will give you an incorrect result if the date and time are not in the same daylight savings rule. Your time will be an hour off, depending on the timezone rules. Here's a simple way to avoid daylight savings issues:

```js
const mergeDateAndTime = (date, time) => {
  const newDate = new Date(date);

  newDate.setHours(time.getHours());
  newDate.setMinutes(time.getMinutes());
  newDate.setSeconds(time.getSeconds());
  newDate.setMilliseconds(0);

  return newDate;
};
```

Answer (score -3):

You could use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/):

```
var firstvar="2018-01-19T00:00:00.000Z";
var secondvar="2018-05-20T00:06:30.000Z";
var thirdvar=moment(firstvar).format("YYYY-MM-DD") + moment(secondvar).format("THH:mm:ssZ");
```

You split the `datetime` objects on `date` and `time` first, and then connecting it together
the `thirdvar` will result in `2018-01-19T00:06:30.000Z`

Comment: Why the imperative "have to"?   There are alternative libraries other than moment.js like 'date-fns' and others.